# Vaadin JPAContainer max constraint

Tags: hibernate, vaadin

I am using Hibernate in my Vaadin application and which to retrieve a single Entity from my database. This entity is the one with the most recent datetime. I have been looking if I can use a filter on my JPAContainer which allows me to set a MAX constraint but have had no luck so far.

Can someone explain how I can achieve this MAX constraint and thus retrieve the entity with the most recent datetime?

Comment: Order by date descending and then use the top most entry?

Comment: Isn't that a bit cumbersome to sort all the data first and then just take the top one?

Comment: Yes, it is, but the database should handle this, she has anyway to find the latest date...